# Geosparql function

Tags: function, geosparql

I am trying to merge two districts that have WKT coordinates as geoshape attributes. the query is as follow:

```
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX geop: <http://www.opengis.net/def/property/OGC-GeoSPARQL/1.0/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX ext: <http://rdf.useekm.com/ext#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ubmo: <http://w3id.org/UrbanAndBuildingMultiscaleOntology#>
    
select ?quar ?quar1 ?envelope
 where { 
 ?quar rdf:type ubmo:Quartier. 
 ?quar1  rdf:type ubmo:Quartier. 
 Filter(regex(str(?quar), "QuartierF4481__1")).
 Filter(regex(str(?quar1), "QuartierF4481__10")).
 ?quar ubmo:geoshape ?aWKT.
 ?quar1 ubmo:geoshape ?bWKT.
 BIND (geof:union(?aWKT, ?bWKT) AS ?envelope)  
}
```

I am getting the following error for GraphDB:
Error 500: error
Query evaluation error: The validated object is null (HTTP status 500).

Any advice
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using `geof:union` correctly, as per examples at https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/geosparql-support.html
2. Can you show us the two geometries? Use `concat` as a simple way:

```
BIND (concat(?aWKT, ?bWKT) AS ?envelope)
```

3. BTW, filtering on URLs is not the best way, you can just use `bind` or `values`